# JavaScript calculator help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, events

I'm currently programming a calculator which is divided into two sections.  The first section is a textbox which takes a string (an activity the user has entered).  The second section consists of 4 textboxes.  Each textbox requires a number as input.  In the second section of the calculator, the calculator textboxes are labeled days, hours, minutes, and seconds.  The purpose of the calculator is to determine how much money after the activity is complete.  The formula for the activity & code is shown below.

```
MoneyMadeDuringActivity = (NumOfDays * days) + (NumOfHours * hours) + (NumOfMinutes * minutes) + (NumOfSeconds * seconds)

    $(document).ready(function () {

  /**
   * VARIABLES
  ***/
  var activity = $('#txtActivity').text();
  var c = new Calculator();

  var days = $('#txtDays').text();
  var hours = $('#txtHours').text();
  var minutes = $('#txtMinutes').text();
  var seconds = $('#txtSeconds').text();

  var MoneyMadeDuringActivity = (days * c.per_day) + (hours + c.per_hour) + (minutes * c.per_minute) + (seconds * c.per_second);


  function listen(event, elem, func) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
      elem.addEventListener(event, func, false);
    } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
      var r = elem.attachEvent("on"+event, func);
      return r;
    }
  }

  listen("click", $("#btnCalculate"), (function() {
    $("#CalcOutput").text(
      "In the time it takes me to " + activity + ",<br />" + "Barack Obama makes " + "$" + MoneyMadeDuringActivity
    );
  });

});
```

My problem occurs with getting the output to work.  I can't get anything to be displayed.  I have the div tag with an id="CalcOutput", so I don't know why it won't display correctly.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw you're trying to insert html with the text method, this is wrong, you html method instead.

```
$("#CalcOutput").html(
      "In the time it takes me to " + activity + ",<br />Barack Obama makes $" + MoneyMadeDuringActivity
    );
```

---

**EDIT**

This way worked for me.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      //mocking up your Calculator class
      function Calculator(){
        this.per_day = 345665;
        this.per_hour = 67845;
        this.per_minute = 1234;
        this.per_second = 789;
      }

      $(document).ready(function () {

        function calculate(){
          var activity = $('#txtActivity').val();
          var c = new Calculator();

          var days = +$('#txtDays').val();
          var hours = +$('#txtHours').val();
          var minutes = +$('#txtMinutes').val();
          var seconds = +$('#txtSeconds').val();

          var MoneyMadeDuringActivity = (days * c.per_day) + (hours + c.per_hour) + (minutes * c.per_minute) + (seconds * c.per_second);

          $("#CalcOutput").html(
            "In the time it takes me to " + activity + ",<br />Barack Obama makes $" + MoneyMadeDuringActivity
          );
        }


        $("#btnCalculate").click(function() {
          calculate();
        });

      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    activity:
    <input type='text' id='txtActivity' value='foobar' /><br/>
    days:
    <input type='text' id='txtDays' value='3'/><br/>
    hours:
    <input type='text' id='txtHours' value='12'/><br/>
    minutes:
    <input type='text' id='txtMinutes' value='34'/><br/>
    seconds:
    <input type='text' id='txtSeconds' value='37' /><br/>
    <button id='btnCalculate'>Calculate</button><br>
    <div id="CalcOutput"></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I changed .text() to .html(), but I'm still not getting anything. :(

Comment: ok, anyway this is a mistake, wait a minute, I'm testing your code.

Comment: What do you mean.  How would I implement this?

Comment: If the elements are inputs, use .val() not text().

Comment: I made corrections from both alcides and JNo, but I'm still not getting any output.  I have the div styled to the point where the text should be easy to see.

Comment: If you copy the above code in a new file, it will work. Something in your code (that you didn't post here) is causing this behavior. Could you please post the rest of your code?

Comment: @Jan, this is not necessary, I used the unary + operator, which do this work .

Comment: Wow, you were right the code does work.  I'm so dumb I so focused on the js that I forgot that I didn't have the script tag included on the html file.  Thanks you guys.